Origin of "De gustibus non est disputandum"
The origins of the phrase De gustibus non est disputandum do not seem to be well documented.
Some references say "an ancient Roman adage"; some say "of medieval origin"; others say "a subject of debate": but I cannot find a citation to its use.
Is it really not to be found in any Latin text?
As for its meaning, it is usually translated as "there is no [point in] arguing over taste" (because it's entirely subjective);
but might it possibly mean the opposite: "there can be no argument in matters of taste" -- that taste is in some way beyond dispute, and simply is, or isn't?

@njuffa Seius and Titius were (fictional?) homeowners in ancient Rome. The example with the two houses is taken from the Digests, 17.1.5, which does not include the de gustibus part, though. I think these can be read as "If I commission you to buy the house of Mr. Smith and you buy the house of Mr. Jones" or some such. (Interestingly a domus Seiana is also debated in Varr. R. R. 3, 2 – not sure if this is related, or if it is, how.)

@njuffa Indeed, and the Digests say, nice deal but that wasn't your job, whereas Mr. Montanus seems to think that at least in the specific circumstances he's discussing, one might come to a different conclusion. All of which is probably a bit off-topic, but an interesting tidbit nonetheless.

[I would like to thank @Sebastian Koppehel for the reference to Justinian's "Digest", which allowed me to understand the Latin text quoted below.]
The first occurrence of the idiomatic phrase in print that I could find is
Horatius Montanus, Repetitio legis Imperialem de prohibita feudi alienat. per Fridericum: cum summariis & indice locupletissimo. Naples: Secondino Roncagliolo 1628, p. 31:

Verum est; sed quæso quomodo cognoscitur voluntas usuarii contraria ex hoc tex.? ex causa extrinseca, videlicèt quia proprietarius commutat speciem rei usuariæ; erat enim vinea, ex qua debebatur mihi usus; proprietarius dextruxit vineam, & ædificat magnam domum: tunc licèt ratione rei sit melior conditio usuarii; cum uti domo sit melius, quam uti vinea, vel simili; tamen, quia usuarius utebatur vinea, & ex usu colligebatur eius voluntas, videlicèt utendi vinea; meritò dum licèt respectu rei sit melior; & eodem modo procedit tex. ir l. diligenter.
Mando tibi, ut emas mihi domum Seianam centum; & tu Titianam maioris valoris emis minori pretio centum; affectio mandantis est incerta re, quia de gustibus non est disputandum; merito non valet actus, & præfertur voluntas interesse nummario; quod ego non negabo; dico tamen, quòd dum Dominus assentit vassallo, ut vendat; principaliter eius intentius est, prodesse vasallo; nisi aliud appareat ex circumstantiis concurrentibus; & tunc ubi aliud non appareat, potest actus explicari à vassalo alio modo, quo fuit permissus; ut bene probatur ex d. §. sed si permiserit: at ubi ex circumstantiis constat,assensisse ad certum finem, & causam; tunc, nisi fiat eo modo, quo Dominus vult, assensus nil præstat: quia repugnat voluntati assentientis.

Orazio Montano (or in Latinized form, Horatius Montanus), was a 17th century lawyer in the Kingdom of Naples. In this book he provides legal commentary on legislation promulgated by the emperor Frederick I. (Barbarossa) in 1185 that prohibited the alienation of fiefs. My limited understanding is that alienation meant that a feudal lord would give a fief to a vassal, and sometimes the vassal would then donate a portion of the fief to a religious institution (such as a monastery), or sell a part of it to an expanding city, without the consent of the lord.
In the following I will paraphrase the quoted section, as a precise translation is beyond my capabilities. Corrections and clarifications are welcome.
In this section the author examines the duty of a vassal to his lord by considering two examples of fiduciary duty. The first is about the tenant of a vineyard who destroys it to build a big house on the site. Although a house is more useful than a vineyard, the landowner was counting on being provided with some of the vineyard's harvest. The second example draws on the Digest, a comprehensive collection of Roman laws that the Byzantine emperor Justinian commissioned in A.D. 533. In section 17.1.5.2 of the Digest, someone is commissioned to purchase the house of Sejanus for a hundred units of currency, but instead buys the house of Titian, which is of far greater value and acquired at a cost of hundred currency units or even less. Nonetheless, under the law, the person commissioned has not fulfilled their client's mandate (here, Sejanus and Titian are placeholder names, like Alice and Bob in modern cryptography).
Montano appears to disagree and states that the client's attitude towards this is uncertain, because there is no point in arguing about taste: the client may prefer that their instructions are followed precisely or may prefer the financial advantage achieved in the bargain.

Brilliant. So: "You can't predict what people will like" (as in the usual translation "There's no accounting for taste"); rather than an exhortation that "you shouldn't argue about matters of taste.".
